# How can I get list_fields of a table alias using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this model:

```
public function listar_jogos_fase($id_fase) {
    $this->db->select('fas.nome as `fase`, jogos.numero as `jogo`, jog1.nome as `jogador1`, jog2.nome as `jogador2`, jogos.data as `data`, jogos.hora as `hora`, jogos.local as `local`', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('jogos');   
    $this->db->join('jogadores as jog1', 'ON jog1.id = jogos.jogador1');
    $this->db->join('jogadores as jog2', 'ON jog2.id = jogos.jogador2');
    $this->db->join('fases as fas', 'ON fas.id = jogos.fase');
    $this->db->where('fase',$id_fase);
    $dados['dados'] = $this->db->get()->result();
    $dados['colunas'] = $this->db->list_fields('jogos');
    return $dados;
}
```

So I'd like to receive this result, with only some selected fields of my alias table:

```
fase      jogo   jogador1        jogador2               data        hora            local
1° Fase    1     Andy Murray     Juan Martin del Potro  2017-01-19  16:30:00 Roland Garros, Paris - Quadra 1
1° Fase    2     Novak Djokovic  Roger Federer          2017-01-19  16:30:00 Roland Garros, Paris - Quadra 2
```

But I'm receiving this other, with all the fields of my table:

```
id      fase    numero          jogador1              set1_jg1   set2_jg1  set3_jg1                       set4_jg1 set5_jg1 jogador2 set1_jg2 set2_jg2 set3_jg2 set4_jg2 set5_jg2 data hora local
1° Fase  1      Andy Murray     Juan Martin del Potro 2017-01-19 16:30:00  Roland Garros, Paris - Quadra 1
1° Fase  2      Novak Djokovic  Roger Federer         2017-01-19 16:30:00  Roland Garros, Paris - Quadra 2
```

If I use that:

```
public function listar_jogos_fase($id_fase) {
    $dados['dados'] = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT       
            d.nome fase,
            a.numero jogo,
            b.nome jogador1,
            c.nome jogador2,
            a.data data,
            a.hora hora,
            a.local local
        FROM jogos a
            JOIN jogadores b ON a.id = b.id
            JOIN jogadores c ON a.id = c.id
            JOIN fases d ON a.fase = d.id
        where fase=$id_fase"
    )->result_array();
    
    $dados['colunas'] = $this->db->list_fields('jogos');

    return $dados;
}
```

I'm gonna receive this:

```
Array
(
    [dados] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fase] => 1° Fase
                    [jogo] => 1
                    [jogador1] => Andy Murray
                    [jogador2] => Andy Murray
                    [data] => 2017-01-19
                    [hora] => 16:30:00
                    [local] => Roland Garros, Paris - Quadra 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fase] => 1° Fase
                    [jogo] => 2
                    [jogador1] => Novak Djokovic
                    [jogador2] => Novak Djokovic
                    [data] => 2017-01-19
                    [hora] => 16:30:00
                    [local] => Roland Garros, Paris - Quadra 2
                )

        )

    [colunas] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
            [1] => fase
            [2] => numero
            [3] => jogador1
            [4] => set1_jg1
            [5] => set2_jg1
            [6] => set3_jg1
            [7] => set4_jg1
            [8] => set5_jg1
            [9] => jogador2
            [10] => set1_jg2
            [11] => set2_jg2
            [12] => set3_jg2
            [13] => set4_jg2
            [14] => set5_jg2
            [15] => data
            [16] => hora
            [17] => local
        )

)
```

I know how to work with these results, but I want to use, if possible, the `$this->db->list_fields()` of CodeIgniter to get the name of my alias table fields (alias, not the original).

So if I use `$this->db->list_fields('jogos')`, I will receive all the fields of the original table 'jogos', as you can see in the array `[columns]`.

But I do not want all fields, I want only the 7 fields that were returned in `[data]` array that are: `[fase],[jogo],[jogador1],[jogador2],[data],[hora],[local]`.

I'd like to use something like `$this->db->list_fields('a')`, where `'a'` is an alias of my original table 'jogos'. But if I use that `$this->db->list_fields('a')`, I get this error:

```
    Error Number: 42S02/1146
    
    Table 'tennis.a' doesn't exist
    
    SHOW COLUMNS FROM `a`
    
    Filename: C:/wamp64/www/tennis/system/database/DB_driver.php
    
    Line Number: 691
```

How can I do this? Is it possible at all?

Comment: `print_r( $dados['dados']);` what is output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   public function listar_jogos_fase($id_fase) 
{
      $this->db->query("SELECT 
      fas.nome fase,
      a.numero jogo,
      b.nome jogador1,
      c.nome jogador2,
      a.data data,
      a.hora hora,
      a.local local
      FROM jogos a
      JOIN jogadores b ON a.id = b.id
      JOIN jogadores c ON a.id = c.id
      JOIN fases d ON a.fases = d.id
      where fase=$id_fase")->result_array();
}
```